# How to add a tooltip to fancybox plugin?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the fancybox 2 plugin with a bootstrap 3 framework.
I'm trying to figure out how to add a tooltip that appears when the mouse hovers over the image (before it is opened).

This works (over text):

```
<a href="#" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add yourself to this post">Show tooltip</a>
```

But I'd like to intergrate the tooltip with this:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="image_1.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Image Title"><img class="img-responsive" src="image_1.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); //Load tooltip


            $('.fancybox').fancybox(); //Load fancybox
    });
```

Any idea how I can do this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u should use "popover" instead "tooltip", so is basically the same... data-toggle="popover" and data-content="Some content inside the popover"

to launch:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

Note: if u want to use it in lightboxes, check the z-index, because in the most of cases, the lightboxes contents have higher z-index numbers to show in front, in my case i use lot of popover, so i had to set a higher z-index like:

```
.popover{
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but having trouble getting the popover to appear when placed within the fancybox link. Like this: <a class="fancybox" href="image_1.jpg" ta-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Image Title"><img class="img-responsive" src="image_1.jpg" alt="">
</a>

Comment: u write ta-placement="bottom" is data-placement="bottom" with the DA, check that first

Answer (score 1):

Note 2: if u doesnt get working with the default popover, u can use another way from jquery (using popover). ive created a snippet to get it working easy.

Place in document ready:

```
//New title attribute using popover (start)
$(document).on("mouseenter", "*[title2]", function() {

    $(this).popover({
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        placement: $(this).attr("title2_pos"),
        content: function () {
            return $(this).attr("title2");
        }
    });

    $(this).popover('show');
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", "*[title2]", function() {

    $(this).popover('destroy');

});
//New title attribute using popover (end)
```

so, in ur html code u can use easy like this:

```
<a href="#myurl" title2="Hello world" title2_pos="bottom">My button</a>
```

as far i remember u can use position top,bottom,left,right

EDIT: u can use in any html tag, divs tables links etc... just add the title2 attributes